# many-to-one or many-to-as-a-group matching / assignment

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, matching

I'm looking for a way to solve a many-to-one assignment. At least I believe it is called this way. To be more precise I do not want to assign several objects of one kind to one object of another kind. Instead I want to assign several objects to each other. This shall be done always in quartets.
In case of one-to-one with two different sets this is "easy" done by the hungarian algorithm. In case of only one set I'm using blossom v to assign one-to-one objects of the same kind. Now I need to assign many-to-one objects of the same way.
The only restriction is a minimum weighted problem. The distance will be specified by the euclidean distance.

Can you tell me how to proceed? How do I construct the edges? Up to now I only used symmetric matrices to represent the costs or edges of an element against to the other elements.

[image]

So how to do this when assigning more than one object to another object?

Here's an example of the motivation (don't know why the pictures are always that huge):

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario is known as a hypergraph respectively matching on hypergraphs